# How to join the result of different aggregate function in the same query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Let's say that I have a table called *Patients* and in this table there's a column *age*. I want to know who **are** the oldest **patients**, the youngest **patients** and the average age among them.

So, given the table:

Patients 
Name:      Text 
Age:       Integer

1. Who are the oldest patients in the db?

For this I'm doing:

```
select name, age from patients
where age = (select max(age) as 'HighestAges' from patients)
group by name;
```

This way I was able to retrieve every patient taht have the higher ages (if the is more than one patient with the same age in the result).

2. Who are the youngest patients?

Well, what I need to do is just change the aggregate function and I'll get the expected result, right? So I did:

```
select name, age from patients
where age = (select min(age) as 'LowestAges' from patients)
group by name;
```

And I retrieved any patient who have the lowest ages.

3. What is the average age among all patients?

I just select the average age and nothing more:

```
select avg(age) as 'AverageAge' from patients;
```

So far so good, now here's the big deal: **how do I show the result of these 3 queries in a single result set?**

What i want to achieve is a result set like this:

```
Name       HighestAges     Name     LowestAges     AverageAge
Rosemary       62        Tomalino       22             42
Mat            62        Rocat          22             42
```

You might be thinking "what a stupid result is that?" and you are right, it's just as stupid as it seems and that's why I want to do it, because it's stupid and no one would do it this way. I know there might be thousands of ways of doing it, I want to hear (read) all the ideas. I'm just doing it for fun, I'm learning SQL so I'm not expirienced with it. I learned o lot about full joins, outter joins, inner joins and self joins, I've tried to do them all for about 2 days, but I couldn't get done with it by myself so I'm seeking for help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I removed the "mysql" tag.  SQL Server and T-SQL are basically synonymous, and they are not MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in several ways.  Here is one way that builds on your queries, by moving the `=` subquery to the `from` clause:

```
select p.name, p.age, maxage, minage, avgage
from patients p cross join
     (select max(age) as maxage, min(age) as minage, avg(age) as avgage
      from patients
     ) pp
where age in (maxage, minage);
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Uhnn let me ask you something, can you tell me how this stuff works?

Answer (score 0):

How about this? The solution returns all combinations of "highest-lowest".

```
--Sample table
if object_id(N'tempdb..#patients') is not null drop table #patients;
select [name] = N'name1', [age] = 35
into #patients
union all select N'name2', 28
union all select N'name3', 29
union all select N'name4', 28
union all select N'name5', 28
union all select N'name6', 29
union all select N'name7', 31
union all select N'name8', 35
--select * from #patients

;with cte as
(
    select  [name], [age]
            ,[dr_min] = dense_rank() over(order by [age] asc)
            ,[dr_max] = dense_rank() over(order by [age] desc)
            ,[averageAge] = avg([age]) over()
    from #patients
)
select c1.[name], [highestAge] = c1.[age], c2.[name], [lowestAge] = c2.[age], c1.[averageAge]
from cte as c1
join cte as c2 on c2.[dr_min] = c1.[dr_max]
where c2.[dr_min] = 1 or c1.[dr_max] = 1
order by c1.[name], c2.[name];
```

Comment: It's great, but I don't quite understand it, it's too advanced for me right now. But thank you for introducing me these concepts.

Answer (score 0):

One easier way is to use CTE and cross join

```
;with cte1 as (
select * from patients where age = (
select min(age) from patients )
), cte2 as (
select * from patients where age = (
select max(age) from patients )
), cte3 as (
select avg(age) avgAge from patients)
select c1.name, c1.age as MinAge, c2.name, c2.age as MaxAge, c3.avgAge from cte1 c1 cross join cte2 c2
cross join cte3 c3
```